# DK1203 Flyback SMPS - How does it work?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, ac-dc

Has anyone come across a DK1203 SMPS like this? I've come across ICs like the [FSGN300N](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fsgm300n-d.pdf) that have a startup pin and aux coil to supply the IC. How would the self-supply circuit in the DK1203 work? In the application sample schematic there is no aux coil to charge the cap on VCC and nothing connected to pin 1 (V startup).
[image: Application circuit from datasheet]
I ended with a few of these SMPS failing (they did initially work) after sitting in storage for over a year with no obvious signs of failure or shorted diodes/capacitors (transformer windings also seem ok, though the secondary almost looks like a short but it's only 11 turns...), so I'm wondering if there are some startup conditions needed to get the IC turned on and switching properly.

Datasheet: https://radiolux.com.ua/files/pdf/DK1203.pdf

Comment: Bad capacitors? Some electrolytics will loose their dielectric layer after some time of storage and you need to supply some current before it builds up again. Apply full voltage immediately and they sometimes fail or the inrush current is just too big for some adjacent semiconductor.

Comment: Seems pretty likely, I can’t think of anything else that would cause multiple units to fail in what appears to be the same way. I did test the voltage across the diode bridge and it looks DC from a multimeter. Could be the little tank cap on VCC isn’t holding its nameplate rating anymore or more likely that output cap on the secondary... could be why the winding looks so low resistance on the secondary side... I’ll have to swap it out and check

Comment: Please do and report back. Wet electrolytic capacitors are bad in every aspect except price. I’ve had the same issue happening to me where we had to gently soft-start boards which had been in storage for too long before shipping them out to customers. It only take a few seconds to build up the dielectric layer in them.

Comment: Is this an equivalent device to NCP1240?

Comment: Get out also of Y1 ... You are never sure that it is wired to Neutral ... if one has a 3x220V ac without Neutral wire.

Comment: I took out all the electrolytic caps and tested them and they seemed fine. Still very low impedance across the secondary with the caps out. The secondary side isn't exactly as shown in the datasheet, there is quite a small 3 pin device that I can't read the markings on (presumably a linear voltage regulator) and what looks like a zener diode. I'll see if I can get it off and just check the output on the windings

Comment: Make sure you place about 47uF capacitor at the VCC pin (pin#2).

Comment: Hi JBD, welcome to the site! Since yours is the first answer to this question, would you be able to edit your post and provide a little bit more detail? It's not clear to me why this capacitor is needed.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? || A 6V3 zener on pin 2 (maybe lower) MAY help - by keeping Vcc in range if there are Vcc transient issues due to failing capaitor. Vcc absmax is 8V but wkg is 4-6V. It lists a "protect voltage" on Vcc which is presumably an internal zener or equivalent. Helping it may help.

Comment: JBD: They say the cap SHOULD be 22 uF. | I will convert this to a comment. When you have slightly more rep you will be able to comment.